# How do we prevent underscore being used as a control key indicator?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu-items

I am trying to add a menuitem, like this:

```
Items.Add(new MenuItem()
{
    Header = var_from_a_loop;
});
```

The var_from_a_loop has some underscores. Say, var_from_a_loop = "A_B_C_D". When run, this becomes "AB_C_D", that is, it removes the first underscore. Now, I know the underscore is treated like a shortcut key indicator (like the above would mean using shortcut Ctrl + B), but I want to disable this. I could probably manage showing the entire string by doing this:

```
Header = "_" + var_from_a_loop
```

But I am looking for a better solution, as the above is kind of 'hacky'.

Comment: You need to escape the underscore, try replacing them all with double underscores.

Answer (score 0):

If you would use `XAML` you can get this to work by using this template:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <TextBlock>_Some text here</TextBlock>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

This then displays the item with underscore included. If you use a `Label` instead of the `TextBlock` it will be evaluated as the shortcut key.
Just for the sake of the example one would use said `ContextMenu` using a `Style`. Say we are adding context menu to a `ListView` items:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"/>
</Style>
```